# primes collection - countPrimesSmallerThanX

Tags: java, collections, integer, primes

i hope someone can help me.

My task ist to create a collection that countains all primes till x. In the task before i managed to write a method to check if a number is a prime or not.

```
public boolean isPrime(int n){
    for(int i=2; 2*i<n; i++) {
    if(n%i==0)
    return false;
   }
    return true;
}
```

The hint is that collections do not take ints so i can use autoboxing to solve this. And that i have to look up Integer in the API.

But i have absolutely no idea how to solve this. Do i have to write a string class and "fill" it with the primes with that method? Would be really thankful if someone could explain the solution.

**Edit:** I wrote this, but at the end it shows me an error for "return primes;", saying: incompatible types: java.util.ArrayList cannot be converted to int. 
If i leave it out it says misses return satement

````
 public int countPrimesTill100(){

             ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

              for(int num=2; num<100; num++){
           boolean isPrime=true;
               for(int div=2; div<num && isPrime; div++){
                   if(num%div==0)
                        isPrime=false;
           }
           if(isPrime){
                primes.add(num);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(primes.size());
        return primes;
    }```
````

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem. `Collection` in Java is a generic interface so you can't create a `Collection` using a primitive data type. Instead you can use the Wrapper Class `Integer`. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i didn't fully understand the task either, it is:
create a collection primes and use your isPrime method to fill it with the prime numbers between 1 and x. This won’t work directly, because collections don’t take ints. You can use autoboxing to solve this.(look up Integer in the API and use this)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have your algorithm to check whether a number is prime you can create a `List`, which implements `Collection` just like this:

```
List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then if your number is prime add it to your list like this:

```
primes.add(n);
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

This error occurs because your method return type is just an `int`.

Your Method should look like this:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> countPrimesTill100() {
  //do your sutff here.
}
```

and you should be fine.

I recommend you google this stuff before you write a question here because these problems can be easily solved by googling.

sorry for my late reply.

Comment: could you please check my edited question? i think i figured it out but have problems with the return statement